# REST controllers with same Path

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey

I'm using Spring frame work with jersey to implement REST.
I have a 2 sets of paths in the following patterns

Set 1:

```
/top/{top_id}/<some string>
ex:

/top/{top_id}/book

/top/{top_id}/pen

/top/{top_id}/dog
```

Set 2 :

```
/top/{top_id}/middle/{middle_id}/<some string>
ex:

/top/{top_id}/middle/{middle_id}/book

/top/{top_id}/middle/{middle_id}/pen

/top/{top_id}/middle/{middle_id}/dog
```

Since these work on different levels ( set 1 on top level and set 2 on middle level) , I want to create different controllers classes for them.

```
    @Component
    public class Top{
    }

    @Component
    public class Middle{
    }
```

The problem I'm having is both sets have /top/{top_id} common.

I don't know what to use as the value for @Path annotation written above the class. I tried removing it, but Jersey is not recognizing the class. Please suggest a method to implement this. I'm trying to do this because there are around 100 paths in each layer. I don't want to keep them all together in a single file. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to use the same `@Path("/top/{top_id}")` on *both* classes? Jersey should be able to figure out which path is handled by which class.

Comment: @LutzHorn, It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through  [orcale docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/6nisfjmk8/index.html) , I found a way to make it work.

```
@Path("/top/{top_id}")
@Component
public class Top{

  @GET
  @Path("/book")
  @Produces({"application/json"})
  public getBooks(){
  }

}

@Path("/top/{top_id}/middle/{middle_id}")
@Component
public class Middle{

  @GET
  @Path("/book")
  @Produces({"application/json"})
  public getBooks(){
  }

}
```

It works. Using like this they can be split into different controller files.